# Host-independent URL from code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need my app to send email with a link back to the app in it.  How do I form the link, no matter which host/port/etc it is running on?  In one place, I do this:

```
var urlToSend = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + "some/path";
```

But I don't have simple access to the `req` object in my new case.  That string manipulation seems goofy and error-prone to begin with.  Jumping through hoops to get the request would make it even worse, I think.

Is there something in nodejs like [url helper functions in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at those URL helper functions, I don't see any that give you the hostname. You're right in that capturing it from `req.hostname` is a bit sloppy.

I'd recommend conditionally setting an environment variable as long as your setup isn't too complex. After that, use the `url` module that [McMath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4311245/mcmath) mentioned.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  process.env.HOSTNAME = "site.com"
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  process.env.HOSTNAME = "localhost"
}
```

Comment: In that doc, after the path helpers, it mentions that there are equivalent _url helpers that generate full URLS.  Thanks for this help.  I guess env variables is the state of the art in nodejs.  (I will also take @McMath's advice for better url building code.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`url`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module in Node. [`url.format()`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_format_urlobj) should serve your purposes. For example, you can do something like this:

```
'use strict';

const url = require('url');

// Just for example:
const PROTOCOL = 'https';
const HOST = 'some.host.com';
const PATH = 'some/path';

// ...

var urlToSend = url.format({
  protocol: PROTOCOL,
  host: HOST,
  pathname: PATH
});

// urlToSend = 'https://some.host.com/some/path'
```

You shouldn't need access to the `req` object just to construct a link. The relevant protocol, host, path, etc., should all be available somewhere in your app, unless there is something I'm missing about your question.

#### Update

I agree with [@MitchLillie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35583051/4311245) that you should make your app configurable using [environment variables](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env). I just thought I would expand on a suggestion I make in the comments below. It is a common pattern in Node to have a file (or perhaps several files) specifically for configuration, such as setting your host, port, etc. The file would normally contain default values that you could optionally override with environment variables, like so:

```
// config.js

module.exports = {
  protocol: process.env.PROTOCOL || 'https',
  host: process.env.HOST || 'some.host.com',
  // ...
};
```

And then you can just `require('./config.js')` wherever you need access to these settings. It helps to maintain consistency as your app grows, and makes it easy to change your settings if necessary.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I'm taking the @Mitch advice to use env variables, and this better code to build urls is helpful, too.

Comment: I'm glad to help. I wasn't sure if you were asking about how to get the variables in the first place, but I would also recommend environment variables, or perhaps a separate config file in which to keep your settings, perhaps allowing them to be optionally overridden by environment variables.